# Number of ways of distributing 7 distinct balls into 7 distinct boxes with exactly one box with 3 balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is what I tried. I can distribute the balls in four ways:

1) 3,1,1,1,1

2) 3,2,1,1

3) 3,2,2

4) 3,4

For 1) I can first pick 5 boxes in ${7 \choose 5}$ ways and then pick 3 balls in ${7 \choose 3}$ ways. Moreover, I can permute this selection $5!$ ways.

For 2)-4) in a similar fashion: ${7 \choose 4}{7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}{2\choose 1}4!$; ${7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}{7 \choose 3}3!$; ${7 \choose 2}{7 \choose 3}2!$

I am not sure if I these numbers are correct (I feel like I double counted somewhere). Also, is there an alternative (or perhaps better) way to approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We give an alternate approach that (barely) involves cases.  It will give a number to check your answer against.

The box that gets $3$ balls can be chosen in $7$ ways, and for each way the balls it gets can be chosen in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.

What about the rest? The remaining $4$ balls can, *almost*, be assigned in $6^4$ ways. Except that we do not want any of the remaining boxes to have $3$ balls.

How many bad distributions are there? The box that gets $3$ can be chosen in $6$ ways, and the balls it gets can be chosen in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways, with the remaining ball assigned in $5$ ways. Thus the total is 
$$7\binom{7}{3}\left(6^4 -(6)\binom{4}{3}(5)\right).$$

More or less equivalently, we can use Inclusion/Exclusion more explicitly. Call the boxes $1$ to $7$. For each $i$, there are $\binom{7}{3}6^4$ ways of assigning $3$  balls to Box $i$, with the rest distributed among the others.

If we add up, $i=1$ to $7$, we will have double-counted the situations where two boxes get $3$ balls. But we want to count these **no times**.

So from $7\cdot \binom{7}{3}\cdot 6^4$ we must subtract $2\cdot \binom{7}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}\cdot 5$.

Comment: I can't upvote but thanks for your answer- a much simpler approach!

Comment: Counting can be tricky. Let us find the number of $3$-$2$-$2$ to compare with yours. The box that gets $3$ can be chosen in $7$ ways. The balls can be chosen in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways. The two that get $2$ each can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. The lower numbered one of these can be filled in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. I think if you check you will see that you got twice that. Happens a lot.

Comment: By your method, for exactly two boxes it would be $7 {7 \choose 3} (6) {4 \choose 3}(5)$ which is just the number of bad boxes you mentioned, correct?

Comment: I don't understand what "it" refers to. If it is the number of distributions of type $3$-$2$-$2$, that is $7\cdot \binom{7}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$. For comparison with your number, it is $7\cdot \binom{7}{3}\cdot 90$. Exactly two boxes have $3$ is $\binom{7}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}\cdot 5$, and we subtract **twice** this number (second approach) to compensate for the fact that these bad which have been double-counted must be counted $0$ times.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. By it I mean the number of ways of distributing 7 distinct balls into 7 boxes with exactly two boxes with three balls. This is the number of bad boxes, no?

Comment: The number of bad distributions is half that, the components are given in my previous comment. In the Inclusion/Exclusion version, we needed to subtract twice that. In the first approach, we subtract $6\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot 5$ from $6^6$. Same result. The Inclusion/Exclusion version is somewhat more formal, and is in line with care about double-counting.